# Nested Array in JSON: Push / Unshift with date object creates double entry

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour with JavaScript. I am trying to construct a JS object like this in JavaScript (node.js/express)

```
var docAudit = {date: nowObj, changed: {}};
docAudit.changed['N5'] = 'DieterDorian';
```

console.log(docAudit) prints out now as expected:

```
{ date: Thu Sep 04 2014 11:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST),
  changed: { N5: 'DieterDorian' } }
```

Now I want to push or unshift this docAudit object into my 'historie' Array in my 'ip' JSON (fetched from mongoDB)

```
ip: {
    __v: 15
    _id: "53fb42bf52b6542527cb7d23"
    aktuell: {
        N5: "HansHerschel"
        Auftragsnr: "2018"
    }
    historie: [
       {
           date: "2014-09-04T09:53:20.533Z"
           changed: {
           N5: "HansHerschel"
       }
    ]
}
```

Now this operation:

```
ip.historie.unshift(docAudit);
```

should result in adding the docAudit object in front of the historie array inside the 'ip' JSON object. However what happens is this:

```
    ip: {
    __v: 16
    _id: "53fb42bf52b6542527cb7d23"
    aktuell: {
          // not important what happens here
    }
    historie: [
       {
           date: "2014-09-04T11:00:00.533Z"
           changed: {
           N5: "DieterDorian"
       },
       {
           date: "2014-09-04T11:00:00.533Z"
       },
       {
           date: "2014-09-04T09:53:20.533Z"
           changed: {
           N5: "HansHerschel"
       }
    ]
}
```

So what happens is an additional Date object gets pushed into the 'historie' array. I am thinking I might constructing the 'docAudit' object wrongly. Expected output is just to push the docAudit into the array without an additional date object.

Or if I print out the 'ip' object with `console.log(ip)`:

```
{ changed: {}, date: Thu Sep 04 2014 11:48:51 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
     { date: Thu Sep 04 2014 11:48:51 GMT+0200 (CEST),
       changed: [Object] } ] }
```

This is my routing code:

```
  updateIP = function(req, res) {

    return IP.findById(req.params.id, function(err, ip) {
      if(!ip) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        return res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
      }

      var docAudit = {'changed':{}, 'date': nowObj};
      docAudit.changed.N5 = 'DieterDorian'    
      ip.historie.unshift(docAudit);   

      ip.markModified('aktuell');
      ip.markModified('historie'); 

      return ip.save(function(err) {
        if(!err) {
          console.log('Updated');
          return res.send({ status: 'OK', ip:ip });
        } else {
          if(err.name == 'ValidationError') {
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.send({ error: 'Validation error' });
          } else {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.send({ error: 'Server error' });
          }
          console.log('Internal error(%d): %s',res.statusCode,err.message);
        }
        res.send(ip);
      });
    });
  };
```

**Update:**

I think the question is whether the following broken-down code is correct:

```
 updateIP = function(req, res) {
     return IP.findById(req.params.id, function(err, ip) {

         // alter the ip JSON here...

         ip.save(function(err) {
             if(!err) {
                 return res.send({ status: 'OK', ip:ip });
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your 'ip' structure is not proper, i have corrected it:

```
ip: 
     {
      __v: 15,
     _id: "53fb42bf52b6542527cb7d23",
      aktuell: {
        N5: "HansHerschel",
        Auftragsnr: "2018"
      },
      historie: [
       {
           date: "2014-09-04T09:53:20.533Z",
           changed: 
           {
             N5: "HansHerschel"
           }
       }
     ]  

     };
```

on applying,

```
var count = ip.historie.unshift(docAudit);
```

I get the proper expected result, and get the count as 2.

```
{"__v":15,"_id":"53fb42bf52b6542527cb7d23",
"aktuell":{"N5":"HansHerschel","Auftragsnr":"2018"},
"historie":[
{"date":"x","changed":{"N5":"DieterDorian"}},
{"date":"2014-09-04T09:53:20.533Z","changed":{"N5":"HansHerschel"}}
]}
```

Check if you are doing two upshifts.

Comment: You are correct, the error must be somewhere else in my code. I will update my Question, maybe you can see an error with my express/node code?